# Why won't pdf2john extract the password hash of this encrypted pdf? Getting blank results

Tags: password-cracking, pdf, hashcat, john-the-ripper

New to the community, and to JtR and Hashcat as a whole, but after searching for a few days I couldn't find a solution to this specific problem.

I have a password protected PDF file that I'm trying to crack to prove to a friend of mine that it can be done (or not as the case may be).

The problem is this: 
I run `pdf2john.pl` on the file and put it out to a `.txt` or hash file. However, all I get is `"name.pdf: "` and nothing where the hash should be. Am I doing something wrong, or does `pdf2john` not work for this instance?

Comment: Check if your system has perl installed.
In my case, I installed "perl" and hash was displayed.

Answer (score 4):

Does it work when you try to encrypt and crack a PDF yourself?

Here is a rundown on encrypting and cracking it with the tools you described:

- Get a sample PDF file `sample.pdf`.
- Encrypt it. I'm using [`qpdf`](https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf) with the password `abc123`.

  ```
  $ qpdf --encrypt abc123 abc123 256 -- sample.pdf sample_encrypted.pdf
  ```
- Extract the hash.

  ```
  $ ./pdf2john.pl pdf-sample_encrypted.pdf > pass.john
  ```

  (I used `pdf2john.pl` from [here](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl).)
- Crack the hash.

  ```
  $ john pass.john
  Loaded 1 password hash (PDF [MD5 SHA2 RC4/AES 32/64])
  Will run 4 OpenMP threads
  Press 'q' or Ctrl-C to abort, almost any other key for status
  abc123           (sample_encrypted.pdf)
  1g 0:00:00:35 DONE 2/3 (2018-04-12 13:37) 0.02787g/s 585.4p/s 585.4c/s 585.4C/s 123456..franklin

  Use the "--show" option to display all of the cracked passwords reliably
  Session completed
  ```

If it works when you encrypt it following these steps, but not with the file you got, consider that the file may be corrupt or encrypted with an unsupported method. Ask your friend how he encrypted it and try to reproduce it with his approach. Ultimately, without access to the file it's hard to pin down out where exactly you went wrong.

Comment: alright im having trouble posting this comment, so bear with me. 

worked using those steps. using pdf-parser.py gives me this info about the encryption via obj26

`obj 26 0
 Type: 
 Referencing: 

  <<
    /Filter /Standard
    /V 1
    /R 2
    /O '(\xe0EA\x10\x08\xd1\xa3\xa9KK\xa8\x1e,\x16\xcf\x8ft\x9bR<\xd64\xa0\xeb\x19sd\\r\x98\\(\xe8])'
    /U '(\xe7\x81\xc9\xc9X\x91\xbd\xf6\xbf:n\x83\xc8\xdc\xee\x11*\xb7\x7fY_\x9f\x8a@C\xf1\x03\xcd\x9c\xf2f\xc8)'
    /P -60
  >>
`